# StackOverFlowException Being called

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

This is my code for instatiating object in DBConnectionClass

```
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public Schools  Schools  = new Schools();
    public Branches Branches = new Branches();
    public Students Students = new Students();
```

And this is DBConnection class constructor :

```
      public DbConnectionClass()
      {
        ConnectionString = "Data Source=LRO-SH-32;Initial Catalog=DatabaseDB;Integrated Security=True";
        Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Con.Open();
      }
```

Here are some query variables:

```
    public string InsertAllQuery = " INSERT INTO Schools ( SchoolName, SchoolLocation, SchoolPhoneNo, SchoolEmailId) VALUES (@SchoolId, @SchoolName, @SchoolLocation, @SchoolPhoneNo, @SchoolEmailId) ";
    public string UpdateAllQuery = " UPDTAE Schools SET (SchoolName=@SchoolName, SchoolLocation=@SchoolLocation, SchoolPhonNo=@SchoolPhoneNo, SchoolEmailId=@SchoolEmailId) WHERE Id=@Id ";
    public string DeleteAllQuery = " DELETE FROM Schools WHERE Id=@Id ";
    public string SelectAllQuery = " SELECT * FROM Schools WHERE Id=@Id";
    // DbConnectionClass newDbInstance = new DbConnectionClass();
    public string SchoolsInsertQuery {
        get { return InsertAllQuery; }
        set { InsertAllQuery = value; }
    }
```

Here is my Final query :

```
   public string InsertQuery
    {
        get { return InsertAllQuery; }
        set { InsertAllQuery = Schools.SchoolsInsertQuery + Branches.BranchInsertQuery + Students.StudentsInsertQuery ; }

    }
```

This is complete class code :

```
       public class DbConnectionClass
{
//Connection String


    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public Schools  Schools  = new Schools();
    public Branches Branches = new Branches();
    public Students Students = new Students();

    //Queries 

    public string InsertAllQuery { get; set; }
    public string UpdateAllQuery { get; set; }
    public string DeleteAllQuery { get; set; }
    public string SelectAllQuery { get; set; }
    public string InsertQuery
    {
        get { return InsertAllQuery; }
        set { InsertAllQuery = Schools.SchoolsInsertQuery + Branches.BranchInsertQuery + Students.StudentsInsertQuery ; }

    }



//Starting Database connection definition
    public SqlConnection Con;
    public DbConnectionClass()
    {
        ConnectionString = "Data Source=LRO-SH-32;Initial Catalog=DatabaseDB;Integrated Security=True";
        Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Con.Open();
    }

    public void SaveData()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, Con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


    public void DbConnectionClose()
    {
        Con.Close();
    }

}
```

}
Now the problem is, it give Stackoverflow Exception at Line 2 Block 1 of the above code. can you give me an insight of what is happening and how should we deal with it: 
Here is the call stack >

```
         >  SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 15   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.Students.Students() Line 27 C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP.DbConnectionClass.DbConnectionClass() Line 17   C#
SchoolManagementSystemOOP.dll!SchoolManagementSystemOOP._Default._Default() Line 16 C#
[External Code]
```

Here is my code for Students class

```
         public class Students 
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string InsertAllQuery { get; set; }
    public string UpdateAllQuery { get; set; }

    public string DeleteAllQuery { get; set; }

    public string SelectAllQuery {get;set;}

    DbConnectionClass newDbInstance = new DbConnectionClass();

    public string StudentsInsertQuery
    {
        get { return InsertAllQuery; }
        set
        {
           InsertAllQuery = " INSERT INTO AddStudents (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo, EmailId) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @PhoneNo, @EmailId) ";
        }
    }
    //Constructors
    public Students()
    {
    }



}
```

Comment: The use of `InsertQuery`'s setter calling `InsertAllQuery` looks a little suspect. Can you post the class definition (header + inheritance heirarchy)?

Comment: I have updated the question with complete class code : @DiskJunky

Comment: That helps. What about the object `Schools` for example? Is this inheriting from `DbConnectionClass`?

Comment: (maybe) not related, but having a `InsertQuery` setter that ignore the value in input is at least weird (evil would be a better definition). what every developer will expect from a getter/setter is that if I assign a value "x" to a field, and immediatly read the same field, I get "x" and not something else (ok... threading can make things different, but that's another pair of sleeves)

Comment: what is the line 2 block 1 giving you a stack overflow exception? this `public Schools  Schools  = new Schools();`? If so, the problem seems to be in your `Schools` class (does it contains an initalized `Schools` instance?

Comment: Object Schools inherits from Schools class and similarly objects Branches and Students inherit from Branch and Students class respectivly @Disk Junky

Comment: No Schools class does not have any intialized instance is that what I have to do but in what way ? @Gian Paolo

Comment: OK, tackling this another way; when you get your stackoverflow excption, have you looked at the call stack to see what method is repeating?

Comment: no, in your code object (member variable) Schools is an instance of Schools class: an instance of something does not inherit. inheritance is something related to classes, not instances

Comment: Ok if I don't inherit from Schools class can I associate in some way the Schools class to DbConnectionClass so that I can use the queries in Schools class inside DBConnectionClass? Is there some way I can correct my code ? or is it a totally bad approach? @GianPaolo

Comment: I have checked at call stack and have updated the code please see above  @Disk Junky

Comment: Can you share code of Students class?

Answer (score 0):

DbConnectionClass instantiates a Schools object which appears to then intantiate a DbConnectionClass object, creating an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace, `Students.Students()` is instantiating a new instance of `DbConnectionClass()` which creates a new instance of `Students` and so forth